# Possible to receive touch screen events in the background?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get co-ordinates touch screen in a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540076/get-co-ordinates-touch-screen-in-a-background-service)

I'm experimenting with an accessibility project -- is it possible to detect touchscreen events in the background, e.g. from a service?  Assume I'm using a wakelock to keep my service alive in the background.

This is just a proof-of-concept, so I don't have to worry about the battery for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do sounds similar to [Get co-ordinates touch screen in a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540076/get-co-ordinates-touch-screen-in-a-background-service)

I don't know any way to receive the events from the service either, but the suggestion of forwarding the events to your service sounds workable (as long as you are programming all the apps your clients will use yourself)

(There used to be a solution using TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT but this was closed in Android 4)

Comment: Yep; same question.  Thanks.